# Specific splitting sentence by words

Tags: php, regex, split

I have this sentence: `"Hello, how are you?"`. I want to split it by words. I can use the `split()` function, but I want to receive this result:

```
array => [1] 'Hello',
         [2] ', how',
         [3] 'are',
         [4] 'you?';
```

Please help anyone, because I'm not very good with regular expressions. Thank you!

Comment: Why would you want the comma with "how"? Surely you'd want `['Hello',',','how','are','you?']`

Comment: search for the `explode` function on google. I think that's what you want.

Comment: I do the Markov`s chain algorithm text generator, and it seems to be most natural, when comma will be put with word, before which it was in original text, but not after. For example: 'Go, how are you', 'Computer, how are you' and so on.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$result = preg_split('/\b(?=\p{P} )|\b /', 'Hello, how are you?');
```

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly what I`m looking for. I don`t understand, why I got minuses for this question?

Comment: Your example works great but only with English letters. Do you know, how to apply it to cyrillic? For example: 'Привет, как дела?'

Comment: @yura: Try to had a /u modifier: `/\b(?=\p{P} )|\b /u`

Answer (score 0):

This will give more flexibility than preg_split :

```
 # $string = "Hello, how are you?";
 #
 # preg_match_all
 #      (
 #          '/\s*([^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*)/',
 #          $string,
 #          $matches,
 #          PREG_PATTERN_ORDER
 #      );
 #  print_r( $matches[1] );
 # ------------------------------------
 # Result:
 # Array
 # (
 #     [0] => Hello
 #     [1] => , how
 #     [2] => are
 #     [3] => you?
 # )


 # Unicode
 # \s*([^\pL\pN]*[\pL\pN](?:[\pL\pN_-]|\pP(?=[\pL\pN\pP_-])|[?.!])*)

 \s*                       # Strip whitespace
 (
      [^\pL\pN]* [\pL\pN]       # Not letters/numbers, followed by letter/number
      (?:
           [\pL\pN_-]                # Letter/number or '-'
        |  
           \pP                       # Or, punctuation if followed by punctuation/letter/number or '-'
           (?= [\pL\pN\pP_-] )
        |  
           [?.!]                     # Or, (Add) Special word ending punctuation
      )*
 )


 # ASCII
 # \s*([\W_]*[^\W_](?:\w|[[:punct:]_-](?=[\w[:punct:]-])|[?.!])*)

 \s* 
 (
      [\W_]* [^\W_] 
      (?:
           \w 
        |  
           [[:punct:]_-] 
           (?= [\w[:punct:]-] )
        |  
           [?.!] 
      )*
 )
```